# Better way to record users activities in django rest framework

Tags: logging, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for a way of record all users activities in my django rest framework. In other words, I need to record if a user post/put/update/delete something in any model.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? Why isn't it working?

Comment: @wcarhart I tried django-simple-history, but using it I would need a register in each model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have already tried and worked is to create a separate Django model which is responsible for recording user activities. The fields in this model should be:

- a foreign key to the user id
- the method (e.g. POST, GET, PUT, etc)
- the resource that the user is trying to access
- the datetime of the action

After that, the logging of each action will be handled by you explicitly. With this method, you have full control of all the logs and also, you can create some useful views for analytics in the future.

Comment: Hello George. Thanks for you support. Do you have some examples?

Comment: It would be great if you could give us some examples. There are very few of it for django rest.